# Match a set of unicode characters with ctre-unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, c++20, ctre

Say, I have a string

```
char8_t text[] = u8"• test\n - two\n ••    three\n-• four\n";
```

I would like to substitute any number of consecutive blank characters, `-`, or `•` with just a single space. I tried the following:

```
char8_t* b = text + std::size(text)-1;
for (char8_t* r = text;;) {
  auto m = ctre::search<u8R"([\s\-•]+)">(r,b);
  if (!m) break;
  char8_t* w = m.begin();
  r = m.end();
  if (r==b) {
    b = w;
    break;
  }
  *w++ = ' ';
  if (w!=r) {
    memmove(w,r,b-r);
    b -= r-w;
    r = w;
  }
}
*b = '\0';

cout << ((char*)text) << endl;
```

But this results in

```
• test two •• three • four
```

I'm including `<ctre-unicode.hpp>` from [Hana's GitHub repo](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions/).

Is this a bug or the intended behavior?

At first, I thought that maybe the problem is with putting a `•` inside `[]`, because maybe `[]` only accepts single-byte characters and escape sequences, but I get the same output with `(?:[\s\-]|•)+` as with the original `[\s\-•]+`. And `\P{L}+` results in, what I'm assuming is, removal of only some of the bytes comprising the `•` characters:

```
� test two � � three � four
```

Here's a godbolt [link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:34,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:34,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:34,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:34,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Cctre-unicode.hpp%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Ccstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0Ausing+std::cout,+std::endl%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++char8_t+text%5B%5D+%3D+u8%22%E2%80%A2+test%5Cn+-+two%5Cn+%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2++++three%5Cn-%E2%80%A2+four%5Cn%22%3B%0A%0A++++char8_t*+b+%3D+text+%2B+std::size(text)%3B%0A++++for+(char8_t*+r+%3D+text%3B%3B)+%7B%0A++++++auto+m+%3D+ctre::search%3Cu8R%22(%5B%5Cs%5C-%E2%80%A2%5D%2B)%22%3E(r,b)%3B%0A++++++if+(!!m)+break%3B%0A++++++char8_t*+w+%3D+m.begin()%3B%0A++++++r+%3D+m.end()%3B%0A++++++if+(r%3D%3Db)+%7B%0A++++++++b+%3D+w%3B%0A++++++++break%3B%0A++++++%7D%0A++++++*w%2B%2B+%3D+!%27+!%27%3B%0A++++++if+(w!!%3Dr)+%7B%0A++++++++memmove(w,r,b-r)%3B%0A++++++++b+-%3D+r-w%3B%0A++++++++r+%3D+w%3B%0A++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A++++*b+%3D+!%27%5C0!%27%3B%0A%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+((char*)text)+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:ctre,ver:trunk)),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:69.25638179800222,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:30.74361820199778,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: Does CTRE support UTF-8 as a unicode format or does it just search for code units as if it were just a sequence of bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions/issues/243) in the github repo and the author replied.

The Unicode mode of operation is implemented internally by using [`ctre::utf8_iterator`](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions/blob/dee8e701ff9f421cdf8d19925ecb61953740666b/include/ctre/utf8.hpp#L12). But in the current implementation, the use of `utf8_iterator` is triggered only if the `search` function receives `std::u8string_view` as the argument. In the current implementation, a pair of `char8_t*` does not make `search` use `utf8_iterator`.

This is why the [Unicode example](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions#unicode) in the readme and Ted Lyngmo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71486114/2640636) both work in utf8 mode, but my original code works in byte mode.

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about the [ctre](/questions/tagged/ctre) library so I've probably used some clumsy constructs below, but it's hopefully good enough to get somewhere. I've commented inline to explain what it's doing.

```cpp
#include <ctre-unicode.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string_view>

template<class T>
T* get_nonconst_ptr(T* b, const T* e) {
    // a helper to get a non-const pointer to `e`
    return b + std::distance(const_cast<const T*>(b), e);
}

int main() {
    char8_t text[] = u8"• test\n - two\n ••    three\n-• four\n";    

    std::u8string_view tv = text; // a view over the part of `text` left to search

    while(true) {
        auto m = ctre::search<u8R"([\s\-•]+)">(tv);
        if(!m) break; // no match, we're done

        // where to move to
        auto dest = get_nonconst_ptr(text, m.data());

        // where to move from
        auto src = dest + m.size();
        *dest++ = ' '; // replace what was matched with a single space

        // get pointer to end        
        auto end = get_nonconst_ptr(text, tv.end());

        std::move(src, end + 1, dest); // do the move, incl. null terminator

        // a new view over the rest of `text`:
        tv = std::u8string_view(dest, std::distance(src, end));
    }

    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(text) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
 test two three four
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z7PrvhYoT)